# vscode JavaScript - Reference types across files

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense, jsdoc

How can I reference a type that is not exported (like `MyClass`) from another file in VSCode using JavaScript and CommonJS?

I have tried to use `@module` as [dictated by JSDoc](http://usejsdoc.org/howto-commonjs-modules.html) but it does not work. Is this not supported by VSCode?

Let's say I have two files:

**myFactory.js**:

```js
/**
 * @module MyModule
 */

class MyClass {}
const myFactory = {
  create() {
    return new MyClass();
  }
}
module.exports = myFactory;
```

**doSomething.js**:

```js
const myFactory = require('./myFactory');

/**
 * @param {MyClass} item
 */
function doSomething1(item) {}

/**
 * @param {MyModule.MyClass} item
 */
function doSomething2(item) {}

/**
 * @param {module:MyModule.MyClass} item
 */
function doSomething3(item) {}
```

In `doSomething.js`, VSCode's Intellisence is not aware of `MyClass` so all 3 function signatures looks like this:

```js
(local function) doSomethingX(item: any): void
```

Instead of

```js
(local function) doSomethingX(item: MyClass): void
```

Here is my `jsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2017"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to move *MyClass* into separate file and set same *@namespace* for all files:

**MyClass.js:**

```
/** @namespace MyNamespace */

/** This is my class */
class MyClass {}
```

**myFactory.js:**

```
/** @namespace MyNamespace */

const myFactory = require('./MyClass');

const myFactory = {
  create() {
    return new MyClass();
  }
}
module.exports = myFactory
```

**doSomething.js:**

```
/** @namespace MyNamespace */

const myFactory = require('./myFactory');

/** @param {MyClass} item */
function doSomething1(item) {}
```

Comment: This works, but in `MyClass.js` if you export the class it no longer works. Also, the above works without the `@namespace`s.